# async inside init method

Tags: asynchronous, init

I want to make an async method inside ModelUser init. ModelUser init _userId from Parse session here:

```
-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        sqlUserModelImpl = [[UserModelSql alloc] init];
        parseUserModelImpl = [[UserModelParse alloc] init];
        sqlGroupModelImpl = [[GroupModelSql alloc] init];
        parseGroupModelImpl = [[GroupModelParse alloc] init];
        modelUserGroupImpl = [[ModelUserGroup alloc] init];
        sqlUserGroupModelImpl = [[UsersGroupsRelationShipSql alloc] init];
        parseUserGroupModelImpl = [[UsersGroupsRelationshipParse alloc] init];
        _user = [self getCurrentUser];
    }
    return self;
}
```

This the login controller call ModelUser Instance in order to login the app if the user is connected from a previous session:

```
if ([ModelUser instance].user != nil) {

        NSLog(@"username and password were correct");

        //init next controller
        UIStoryboard* sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        screenController* nVC = [sb
                                 instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"screenController"];

        NSString* userId=[[ModelUser instance] getCurrentUser];
            NSLog(@"userId Logged = %@",userId);
            nVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
            [self showViewController:nVC sender:self];

    }
```

The problem is making async "getCurrentUser" because the init method return "self" before the _user parameter get an Id. Then, I get back to the login Controller nil instead of the getCurrentUser result

Comment: It is best to keep init methods as lite as possible. To avoid adding anything that can fail. Further when the init method returns initialization should be  complete, this basically disallows async methods.

Comment: @zaph where do you recommend to call the async method ?? when i do it from the controller it doesn't work for me and I need the user initialized when I call init.

Comment: I have a spinner animator and timeout. Where exactly to call after init?? I can't call it after return self?? @zaph